# Does Win10 interrupt WM_PAINT processing with new WM_PAINT messages?

Tags: windows, winapi

A run-time error's stack trace file shows the window procedure getting called twice with [`WM_PAINT`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd145213.aspx) messages.  The window was in the midst of being repainted due to the first [`WM_PAINT`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd145213.aspx) message (following [`BeginPaint`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vs/alm/dd183362.aspx) but before [`EndPaint`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vs/alm/dd162598.aspx)), when suddenly the window procedure was called again to process a new [`WM_PAINT`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd145213.aspx) message.  Apparently this took place following a call to [`SetBkColor`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd162964.aspx) or [`SelectObject`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd162957.aspx).

I realize this might happen if our application called [`UpdateWindow`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd145167.aspx) (or used [`SendMessage`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644950.aspx) to send [`WM_PAINT`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd145213.aspx) to itself), but I don't believe this ever occurs.  Moreover, [`UpdateWindow`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd145167.aspx) is a no-op if the update region is empty, which should be the case since [`BeginPaint`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vs/alm/dd183362.aspx) validates the update region.

This issue has been reported to us by two customers, both running Windows 10, but otherwise has never been seen before in our long-stable application.  I wonder if possibly Windows 10 (or some transitory Windows 10 auto-update maybe later corrected) could have started to [`SendMessage`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644950.aspx) superfluous [`WM_PAINT`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd145213.aspx) messages?!?  Even if there were some good reason for sending them instead of posting them, it seems unfriendly to force reentrant painting while [`BeginPaint`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vs/alm/dd183362.aspx) is active.

Per request, here's pseudo-code for the stack trace:
*RTS: unhandled exception #3: invalid location*
*BW line 3056 - RepaintChars*
*BW line 3071 - RepaintText*
*BW line 3242 - Repaint (called after [`BeginPaint`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vs/alm/dd183362.aspx) before [`EndPaint`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vs/alm/dd162598.aspx))*
*MAIN line 85 - WindowProcedure (handles [`WM_PAINT`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd145213.aspx) here)*
*Can't recognize module*
*Can't recognize module*
*Can't recognize module*
*BW line 3056 - RepaintChars*
*BW line 3071 - RepaintText*
*BW line 2976 - RepaintAround*
*BW line 3253 - Repaint (called after [`BeginPaint`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vs/alm/dd183362.aspx) before [`EndPaint`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vs/alm/dd162598.aspx))*
*MAIN line 85 - WindowProcedure (handles [`WM_PAINT`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd145213.aspx) here)*
*MAIN lin 145 - main*

Regardless of the possibly-unrelated "invalid location" run-time error at top, I'm trying to understand better here the curious reentrant [`WM_PAINT`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd145213.aspx) messages.  It's possible the top of the stack trace is an illusory repeat of the bottom half, but I don't think so because of slight differences (e.g. no RepaintAround in the top half) and how each location points to meaningful lines that present a consistent picture.

Comment: SetBkColor and SelectObject do not pump messages, so something is wrong. Maybe those functions got detoured? Maybe the stack trace is incorrect?

Comment: ... or in other words - can you post the stacktrace?

Comment: Or an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). That would be excellent.

Comment: Raymond - Thanks for your response!  I'm vague how SendMessage interrupts a thread's processing, so I assumed it happened inside the next WinAPI procedure that gets called.  In this case SelectObject (and before that SetBkColor) were conditionally called immediately before the stack trace showed the window procedure interrupting to handle WM_PAINT, so I guessed that's where it was happening.  Does SendMessage interrupt anywhere regardless of API calls?  My stack trace could be incorrect, but all the line numbers match up to present a consistent picture.

Comment: A window processes inbound messages only when it calls SendMessage to a window on another thread, or when it calls GetMessage or PeekMessage. (Processing at any API call would make programming impossible, because you couldn't even call EnterCriticalSection without risking unexpected reentrancy.) Can you get an exact stack trace? Perhaps your `WM_PAINT` handler is calling a function that in turn calls one of the three functions above, thereby opening the reentrancy window.

Comment: The part you snipped out of the stack trace is the important part.

Comment: _unrecognized procedures_ -- make sure to enable symbol server in VS options to get complete stack trace.

Comment: I really appreciate all these helpful comments!  Raymond, thanks for clarifying that SendMessage happens in the caller's thread... I agree that otherwise programming would be impossible due to unpredictable reentrancy, so what I seemed to be seeing in this stack trace was causing me to doubt reality!  Now I'm back to doubting the stack trace instead of reality.  I've seen enough garbled stack traces that I wouldn't give the time of day, but this one was so consistent that I believed what it was showing me.

Comment: Ben, as you say, the snipped stack trace would be the important part... if it were for real.  Now that I've gotten it out of my head that SendMessage could interrupt the paint thread, I'm more skeptical of what I was seeing in the stack trace.  The snipped part was three lines of "Can't recognize module", which could have been hidden run-time library calls or parameters pushed on the stack at the time of the run-time error.  (BTW, the environment isn't VS.)

Answer (score 0):

Based on comments, I now realize there is no way my [`WM_PAINT`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd145213(v=vs.85).aspx) handler could have been interrupted either externally or internally by calls to SendMessage/GetMessage/PeekMessage, so my stack trace must be incorrect.  My guess is that a shorter [`WM_PAINT`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd145213(v=vs.85).aspx) stack trace may have been laid on top of an earlier longer [`WM_PAINT`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd145213(v=vs.85).aspx) stack trace, forming an apparently consistent story that misled me into thinking that reentrant [`WM_PAINT`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd145213(v=vs.85).aspx) messages were happening.

It still seems possible that a subtle change from some Win10 update may have triggered this run-time error, since it happened in a rock-solid text viewing utility that's barely changed in a decade.  My stack trace did point to a line of code that could be made more resilient against bad data, so hopefully that's resolved.  I appreciate the Stack Overflow community helping me get my head straight about this!